# Find out the length of the longest word from list

Tags: php, string, performance

The list looks like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor
...
```

I want to indent all words like this:

```
Lorem       ipsum       dolor   sit    amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed         do          eiusmod tempor
```

(or at least the first column)

I've managed to do this using arrays and `str_pad`:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$counts = array();

foreach($lines as $line){
  $words = explode(' ', $line);
  foreach($words as $index => $word){
    if(!isset($counts[$index]) || $counts[$index] < strlen($word))
      $counts[$index] = strlen($word);
  }
}

$text = '';

foreach($lines as $line){
  $words = explode(' ', $line);
  foreach($words as $index => $word)
    $text .= str_pad($word, $counts[$index], ' ' , STR_PAD_RIGHT) . ' ';

  $text .= "\n";
}
```

but because the text is very large it uses quite a lot of memory. Is there any other way I can do this, without splitting the text in arrays?

Comment: split to array; use array_map() with strlen() and then find the max() value

Comment: How about taking one line at a time from the string, keep the position of the last line then search from there to the next new line

Comment: @Alex You just want to find the length of the longest word in the string? OR you want to justify the text so it takes up a certain width?

Comment: To justify it. But if I knew how to get the longest word for each column, I could do the rest myself

Comment: Are you working with a set width or are you basing the width on the length of the longest word?

Comment: it should be based on the longest word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is extremely large, you could read the file line by line instead of loading it all into an
array at once with `file()`.

```
$fh = fopen("alice.txt", "r");
$fh = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");

while( !feof($fh) ){

    $line = fgets($fh);
    $Newerline = str_replace("-", " ", $line);

    $textArray = str_word_count($Newerline,1); 

    //now go through the line word by word
    foreach ($textArray as $index => $word){
        trim($word);
        $wordLength = mb_strlen($word);

        //is this word the longest for this column?
        if($wordLength > $longWords[$index]['longestWordlen'] ){
            $longWords[$index]['longestWordlen'] = $wordLength;
            $longWords[$index]['longestWord'] = $word;
        }

    }
    //echo $line;
}
//rewind the file pointer to the beginning
rewind($fh);

ksort($longWords);//associative array will be out of order since longest word shows up differently

//now create a new file to hold the new version
$fileh = fopen( "newFile.txt", "c");

while( !feof($fh) ){
    $line = fgets($fh);
    $Newerline = str_replace("-", " ", $line); 

    $textArray = str_word_count($Newerline,1); 

    $newLine =  "";
    //now go through the line word by word
    foreach ($textArray as $index => $word){
        //set the length of this words column
            $pad_length = $longWords[$index]['longestWordlen'];

            $newLine .= str_pad($word, $pad_length + 1, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    }
    $newLine .= PHP_EOL;

    //save the newLine to file
    fwrite($fileh, $newLine);

    //echo $newLine;
}

fclose($fileh);
fclose($fh);
```

This loads one line at a time and writes one line at a time.  Should use less memory.

Comment: Reading your question again, I realize this isn't what you were wanting. I can't see any way to do this without running through the file twice. First time to find the calulations, second time to create a new line with all the spaces.  If the file is too large, read the file line by line the first time, and during the second run, read line by line but save the result to a new file line by line until you finished.